# How do I make session in CakePHP infinite (or at least longer even when inactive)?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-2.3

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.3 and right now, it's logging me out after about 30 minutes of being inactive. I want the session to last longer (or infinite if possible like Facebook) *even when I leave the site (not closing the browser)* for a couple of hours or so.

I've tried the following on app/Config/core.php but none of these ever worked:

**Test #1:**

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => 60, // The session will timeout after 60 minutes of inactivity
        'cookieTimeout' => 4320, // The session cookie will live for at most 3 days, this does not effect session timeouts
        'checkAgent' => false,
        'autoRegenerate' => true, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
    ));
```

**Test #2:**

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => 2160, // 36 hours
        'ini' => array(
            'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 129600 // 36 hours
        )
    ));
```

**Test #3:**

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
            'defaults' => 'php',
            'cookieTimeout' => 0
    ));
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');
```

I'm not sure now what's going on when the script on the cakephp site itself doesn't work (Test 2). I log in, check other sites then get back to it after an hour then it's logged out. How do I make session in CakePHP infinite (or at least longer even when inactive)?

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP will flush sessions before your timeout will be reached. This can happen on shared hosting machines and heavy traffic. I usually use an own directory to store the sessions: `session_save_path('/path/to/www/session.collection')` . You have to clean them on your own (e.g. using a cron job)

Answer (score 0):

put this in your afterFilter action in AppController:

$this->Session->renew();

This renews the session cookie for infinite.

Otherwise you try below code,

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'database',
        'timeout'=>2441,

    ],
```

add a timeout as per your requirements.

use a session as database, create a session table and it will store session

may be it will help you

Comment: afterFilter is called after the controller action is run and rendered, so if I don't use the site for awhile (no controller is ran), the session will not be renewed still right? and ends up expiring just the same when I get back after a couple of hours?

Answer (score 0):

Put this below code into your project core.php file

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 30000, // The session will timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity
    'cookieTimeout' => 1440, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'autoRegenerate' => true, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
));
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as my Test #1?

Answer (score 0):

In Cakephp 2.4  developers closed the ability to set session.auto_start option from user script.

But there is a work around,

In Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'cookie' => 'myApp',
    //'defaults' => 'php', // Comment this line
    'timeout' => '1440', // Set the timout to 24 hrs
    'autoRegenerate' => true, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
    'ini' => array(
        'session.use_trans_sid' => 0, // use other configuration from php default config
        'session.cookie_path' => "/" // use other configuration from php default config
    )
));
```